# using @html.action to load multiple WebGrids inside the same view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, webgrid

I am working on an `asp.net mvc5` web application, and I need to display multiple `WebGrids` inside the same view, so I use `Html.Action` that returns partial views, where each of the partial views contains one `WebGrid`.
The main view looks as follows:

```
@model SkillManagementTDMGroup.Models.Skill

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<h3>Skill Details</h3>

@Html.Action("GetStaffSkills", "Skill", new  {skillpre = Model.SkillID})</div>
@Html.Action("GetSkillCustomer", "Accounts", new  {customermasterDetail = Model.SkillID})</div>

@Html.Action("GetStaffForSkill", "Staff", new  {staffmasterdetails = Model.SkillID})</div>
```

Each of the `@Html.action` calls call an action method that renders a partial view that containing a `WebGrid`, as follows:

```
public ActionResult GetSkillCustomer(string customerfilter = null, int customerpage = 1, int? customerpageSize = null, string customersort = "Name", string customersortdir = "ASC", int? customermasterDetail = null)
      {
          var records = new PagedList<Customer>();
          records.currentfilter = customerfilter;
          records.Content = unitofwork.CustomerRepository.GetCustomerForGrid(customerfilter, customerpage, customerpageSize.Value, customersort, customersortdir, false, customermasterDetail).ToList();

          // Count
          records.TotalRecords = unitofwork.CustomerRepository.GetCustomerForGridCount(customerfilter, false, true, customermasterDetail);

          records.CurrentPage = customerpage;
          records.PageSize = customerpageSize.Value;
          records.masterDetail = customermasterDetail;

          return PartialView("_gridCustomer", records);
      }
```

Now everything is working well in respect to functionality, where I can sort, page and filter each of the `WebGrids` separately. But the way things are working is not very efficient, because let's say I do a sort inside one of the `WebGrids`, then this will cause the whole chain of action methods to be called, although I only need to update single `WebGrid`. So can anyone advise me if I am doing things correctly? Or is there a better way to do things?

Comment: First of all you need some beginning `<div>` tags, else the `html` will be corrupt.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am already using <div>, but i show only part of the code,, anyway i updated my question ..

Comment: Add some JavaScript for the sorting and replace the table when you get the sorted one from the Action.

Comment: i am using the WebGrid to avoid manully writing javaScripts to do sort, paging , etc... so is there a way to benefit from the WebGrid functionalists but at the same time avoid calling the chain of action methods , when doing a sort or aging inside a single webgrid ?

Comment: @TGlatzer also if i want to load multiple web-grids what are the approaches that i can follow, other than using Html.Action ?

Comment: You could inline them, but if you want to dynamically load parts of your page you will find no (well, except frames, which I'd really not recommend to anyone) way to avoid JS.

Comment: so do you think my current approach is bad ? i mean it is working well ,, but when i checked the sql profiler i found that the whole chain of action methods are going to be called ,,, as part of doing a sort inside single web grid ....